# Seleccionar option de forma dinamica con datos 2 request JQuery

Tags: jquery, json

estoy intentando cambiar un status de Mailbox e intento seleccionar el option correcto de forma dinamica en base a los 2 request que hago, el primero es para traer los datos del formulario que estoy editando y el segundo request es para traer todos los estatus, intento evaluar si cada vez que cambia el option, su valor es igual al valor que trae el primer request, que se seleccione, y cada vez que seleccione para editar el mailbox, tiene que seleccionarse el option del dropdown, pero no logro que se seleccione, funciona si lo pongo en un label pero la idea es hacer lo mismo pero con el dropdown.

Este es mi select:

```
<select class="form-control select2" data-toggle="select2" id="Status" name="Status"></select>
```

El metodo que trae los datos del formulario, cuando edito los datos, aqui es donde tiene que aparecer el option seleccionado con lo que trae el JSON para poder cambiarlo

```
$dataTable.on("click", "a.edit", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Mailbox/GetMailboxById/" + $this.data('id'),
        error: (result) => $.Notification.error(result),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                var mymailbox = result.Mailboxes[0];
                $(FormMB.MailboxStatus).val(mymailbox.MailboxStatus);
                LoadMailboxStatus();
                $('option').each(function () {
                    if (mymailbox.MailboxStatus == $(this).text()) {
                        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected')
                    };
                });
            }
            else {
                $.Notification.error(result.Message);
            }
        }
    });

    $mailboxModal.modal();
});
```

Resultado:

```
"Success": true,
"Message": "",
"Mailboxes": [
    {
        "Date": "2020-04-03T15:35:00",
        "MailboxStatus": "Nuevo",
        "Id": "06d6e6a3-eea2-4bf3-9a37-7c737165256a",
    },
    {
        "Date": "2020-04-03T15:35:00",
        "MailboxStatus": "Atendido",
        "Id": "06d6e6a3-1111-4bf3-9a37-7c737165256a",
    }
```

Metodo que trae los status:

```
function LoadMailboxStatus() {
    var dropDown = $("#StatusId");
    dropDown.empty();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Mailbox/GetStatuses/",
        error: (result) => $.Notification.error(result),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.Success) {
                var status = result.Statuses;
                $.each(status, function (key, item) {
                    dropDown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', item.Id).text(item.Name));
                });
                dropDown.change(function () {
                    $(this).val()
                });
            }
            else {
                $.Notification.error(result.Message);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Resultado:

```
"Success": true,
"Message": "",
"Statuses": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "Nuevo",
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Leído",
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "Name": "Atendido",
    }
]
```

Mi duda es, como podría hacer que se seleccione el option del dropdown en base a lo que traigan los request?

Comment: Puedes utilizar algo como $('[name=options]').val(<valor> ); para seleccionar un elemento en un option. El <valor> lo tomas de tus respuestas a los request

Comment: @MarioL pero en que metodo, cuando llamo los status y dibujo el option, o cuando traigo los datos para editar el form?